# Parse logs on Windows Server 2003 to find user actions

Tags: perl, windows-server-2003, logging

Platform: Windows 2003 with Perl 
I am looking into how to cut the user Id out of the IIS log file. Then find out what that user did. Uploaded file, CWD.. things like that. There is [uniqu_ID]User  ID.  How to retrieve that Id and search for what it did.  Please help.

Comment: Can you please post a few example lines of code? The problem seems rather easy, but examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[Log Parser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en):

> Log parser is a powerful, versatile
>   tool that provides universal query
>   access to text-based data such as log
>   files, XML files and CSV files, as
>   well as key data sources on the
>   Windows® operating system such as the
>   Event Log, the Registry, the file
>   system, and Active Directory®.

Comment: I can't download anything on the server. I have to work with what I have at the moment. Perl on windows 2003

Comment: download to your local box, and process the log there.

Comment: I wish I could... I wrote a perl script that will run on the server itself for status report. the script emails the status report. I can't do that from my PC. it has to run on the server.

Comment: LogParser is Magic for parsing Windows Logs. If you're reinventing the wheel, good luck! It is also accessible via a nice API. You can almost certainly use it from Perl as well.

Comment: It's a trivial problem for perl to solve -- what exactly have you tried writing so far?

Comment: @Chris J: who is your comment directed to? It's an old question....

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of the an IIS log file on Windows 2003 Server [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781851%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Still, please post your own lines of example log.

```
192.168.114.201, -, 03/20/01, 7:55:20, W3SVC2, SERVER, 172.21.13.45, 4502, 163, 3223, 200, 0, GET, /DeptLogo.gif, -,
```

Since this is nothing more than a comma seperated file, you have several different ways to go here. You could use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) if that is installed on your machine. If not, here's a simple example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $user = {}; # we will store the actions in here

# This is what the log file looks like when split into an array
# 0: Client IP address
# 1: User name
# 2: Date
# 3: Time
# 4: Service and instance
# 5: Server name
# 6: Server IP
# 7: Time taken
# 8: Client bytes sent
# 9: Server bytes sent
# 10: Service status code
# 11: Windows status code
# 12: Request type
# 13: Target of operation
# 14: Parameters

open $log, '<', 'path/to/logfile.log';
while (my $line = <$log>) {
  my @fields = split /, /, $line; # split on comma and space
  # you'll get an array of actions for each user
  push @{ $user->{$fields[1]} }, "$fields[12] $fields[13]";  
  # or more specific:
#   push @{ $user->{$fields[1]} }, { 
#     'time' => $fields[3],
#     'action' => $fields[12],
#     'target' => $fields[13],
#   };
}
close $log;

print Dumper $user; # lets have a look

# More stuff to do with the data here...
```

This is the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '-' => [
                   'GET /DeptLogo.gif'
                 ]
        };
```

You could then go and write the contents of `$user` to another file, or group of files.

```
foreach my $u (sort keys %$user) {
  print "$u\r\n";
  foreach $action (@{ $user->{$u} }) {
    print "$action\r\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: @Moe: if answer is not acceptable, please explain why, so one could further dig into your issue.